# how to Stemming Indonesian word with sastrawi

Tags: python

### I did preprocessing the tweet data stored in the vaksinsampel2.csv file. And I have done several steps such as text cleaning, case folding, tokenizing, stopword removal, normalization. but I can't do stemming. please help me solve it.
here the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import re
from Sastrawi.Stemmer.StemmerFactory import StemmerFactory

df = pd.read_csv('vaksinsampel2.csv', encoding = 'unicode_escape')

def remove_punct(tweet):
    tweet = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', ' ', str(tweet))
    tweet = re.sub('[0-9]+', ' ', tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r'#', '', str(tweet))  
    tweet = re.sub(r'http\S+', ' ', tweet)
    return tweet

df['TEXT'] = df['full_text'].apply(lambda x:remove_punct(x))

df['case_folding'] = df['TEXT'].str.lower()

def tokenization(tweet):
    tweet = re.split('\W+', tweet)
    return tweet
df['Tokenization'] = df['TEXT'].apply(lambda x: tokenization(x.lower()))
df.head(10)

stopword = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('indonesian')

def remove_stopwords(tweet):
    tweet = [word for word in tweet if word not in stopword]
    return tweet

df['Stopword_Removal'] = df['Tokenization'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x))
df.head(10)

def normalisasi(tweet):
    kamus_slangword = eval(open("slang_indonesia.txt").read()) # Membuka dictionary slangword
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b( ' + '|'.join (kamus_slangword.keys())+r')\b') # Search pola kata (contoh kpn -> kapan)
    content = []
    for kata in tweet:
        filteredSlang = pattern.sub(lambda x: kamus_slangword[x.group()],kata) # Replace slangword berdasarkan pola review yg telah ditentukan
        content.append(filteredSlang.lower())
    tweet = content
    return tweet
df['Normalization'] = df['Stopword_Removal'].apply(lambda x: normalisasi(x))
df.head(10)

factory = StemmerFactory()
stemming = factory.create_stemmer()
def stem_list(tweet):
        return stemming.stem(df['Normalization'])
df['Stemming'] = df.apply(stem_list, axis=1)
df.head(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

stemmer.stem() and not stemming.stem()?

I am referring to this: https://pypi.org/project/Sastrawi/

(...just happened to start exploring Sastrawi today)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
factory = StemmerFactory()
stemmer = factory.create_stemmer()

def stemming(tweet):
    text = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in tweet]
    return tweet

df['Stemming'] = df['Normalization'].apply(lambda x: stemming(x))
```

Comment: It is not clear how this solves the problem mentioned, with stemming Indonesian word. Please provide enough explanation and link to resources or additional documentation to support your answer.